# iterate threw list and if value doesnt excist hide error and continue

Tags: python, loops, error-handling

I've got a List like:

```
results = ['SDV_GAMMA','SDV_BETA,'...','...']
```

and then comes and for loop like:

```
for i in range (len(results)):
    a = instance.elementSets[results[i]]
```

The strings defined in the result-list are part of a `*.odb` result file and if they didn't exist there comes an error.

I would like that my program doesn't stop cause of an error. It should go on and check if values of the others result values exist.

So i do not have to sort every result before i start my program. If it´s not in the list, there is no problem, and if it exists  i get my data.

I hope u know what i mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `try..except block`

**Ex:**

```
for i in results
    try:
        a = instance.elementSets[results[i]]
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check the presence of results[i] in instance.elementSets before extracting it.

If instance.elementSets is a dictionary, use the `dict.get` command.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get